# SIP SDK for android with G729 codec support

Tags: android, sip

I need to add some basic SIP functionality to my app. I need it to be able to connect to my asterisk server and make SIP audio calls using G729 codec.

Unfortunately the default android SIP api does not support G729 codec (as far as I know), so I can't use it.

I tried to use CSipSimple as library, but it appears not exactly what I need, because I cannot use it as fully standalone library.

So is there any suggestions on what SDK or library I can use to integrate SIP functionality in my app?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using pjsip, is the stack behind CSipSimple, plus adding G729 codec as CSipSimple does, this is, registering it as an external codec into pjsip's media framework.

Inside pjsip's 2.x branch, you can find an example about how to directly use it as a user agent from Android, through a JNI, at: pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/android.

About G729, you can find the code at: jni/g729 and you can build it as a shared library by modifying Android.mk

Hope this helps